# How to configure ELB failover with Active/Standby in same region

Tags: amazon-web-services, failover, amazon-elb

I'm new to AWS and have services running on each instances in same region.
However due to the stability of service, I would need to setup 2 identical instances for Message and put them behind LB group.

I'm now having checks with it and found that every connections I have made are somehow goes to different instances.

I need one single domain point to primary Message server and then switches to secondary when primary is gone for some reasons.

Anyone can give me a advice?

Comment: I'm using socket.io over TCP for connection by nodejs

Comment: Route53 failover routing would be the standard way. If you need the services behind ELB you'd use alias records to point to them. In each ELB spread the servers across AZs.